# Script de cambio de nombre de archivos en python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

tengo que hacer un script en `python 3.5` para que cambiar de nombre los archivos de una carpeta, pero el script no se me ejecuta, no sé por qué.
Gracias  por vustra atención: Aquí os dejo el código:

```
import os
def rename_files ():
    # 1) Vamos a obtener el nombre de los archivos
   file_list = os.listdir ("D:\prank")
   print (file_list)
   saved_path = os.getcwd ()


   print ("El directorio activo es " +str(saved_path))
   os.chdir("D:\prank")

    # 2) Hacemos un bucle que los renombrará uno a uno:
   for file_name in file_list :
      os.rename (file_name, file_name.translate (None, "0123456789"))
os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Comment: Cuando digo que no se me ejecuta, me refiero a que no da error cuando check module.

Comment: Estás definiendo rename_files pero no la estás llamando, te falta `rename_files()` al final del todo

Comment: Me da el siguiente error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\El xaxe\Desktop\Practica carpetas.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.chdir(saved_path)
NameError: name 'saved_path' is not defined

Comment: Tienes que identar os.chdir(saved_path), para que el intérprete reconozca que está dentro de la función rename_files()

Comment: `saved_path` está definido dentro de la función, y por tanto fuera no tiene sentido - tienes que mover esa línea dentro de la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por explicar un poco lo que viene en todos los comentarios. Tu código actual era:

```
import os

def rename_files():
    # 1) Vamos a obtener el nombre de los archivos
    file_list = os.listdir("D:\prank")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()

    print("El directorio activo es " + str(saved_path))
    os.chdir("D:\prank")

    # 2) Hacemos un bucle que los renombrará uno a uno:
    for file_name in file_list :
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))

os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Varias cosas.

- No es necesario hacer `func ()`. De hecho, se desaconseja usar un espacio en la llamada a la función. Mira [aquí](http://pep8.org/#pet-peeves).
- La variable `saved_path` la usas dentro de la función por lo que explícitamente está fuera del *scope* global. Para hacer que esté disponible en el *scope* desde donde la llamas deberías definirla en el *scope* en el que la quieres utilizar y podrías usar `global` o `nonlocal` pero no te lo recomiendo. En realidad no usas esa variable dentro de la función por lo que lo ideal sería que la definieras fuera de la función.
- Cuando haces el `for` renombras todo lo que hay en `file_list` pero si ahí tienes cosas que no son ficheros (directorios, por ejemplo) también se renombrarán.
- Si estás en Python 3 podrías usar la biblioteca `pathlib` para ayudarte en todo el proceso de renombrar y para tener en cuenta si es fichero, directorio, enlace,...
- Estás usando `file_name.translate` pero ese método necesita la salida del método estático `str.maketrans` por lo que te derbería estar dando error.
- Lo ideal sería que la función aceptase el *path* como argumento de tal forma que tu función sería reusable.
- En windows tienes que tener cuidado cuando metes *paths* usando `\` ya que si tienes, por ejemplo, `"D:\nueva_carpeta"`, la parte con `\n` se te convertirá en un salto de línea. Para evitarlo puedes usar el *string* de las siguientes formas: `r"D:\nueva_carpeta"` o `"D:\\nueva_carpeta"`.

Por lo que entiendo, en tu código quieres añadir `0123456789` a cada fichero y no sé si a cada directorio de la misma carpeta.

Tu código transformado podría ser algo como:

```
import pathlib

def rename_files(path, rename_dirs = False):
    print("El directorio activo es " + str(path))
    os.chdir(str(path))
    for f in path.iterdir():
        if rename_dirs and f.is_dir():
            f.rename(str(f) + '_0123456789') # añade _0123456789 al nombre del directorio
        if f.is_file():
            f.rename(str(f).replace(f.suffix, '_0123456789' + f.suffix)) # añade _0123456789 antes de la extensión del fichero

path = pathlib.Path(r'D:\prank')
rename_files(path)
```

Esta solución solo es compatible con Python >= 3.4.x. En las etiquetas has usado `python-3.x` por lo que asumo que te valdrá. Si usas una versión anterior y no tienes muchas dependencias que te lo impidan deberías pensar en actualizarte.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Si no hace lo que deseas, por favor, rehaz la pregunta para poder adecuar el código.

Puedes ver más sobre `pathlib` en el [maravilloso blog de @astrojuanlu](http://pybonacci.org/2016/05/18/joyitas-en-la-stdlib-pathlib/).

Answer (score 1):

Duda formulada hace 10 meses pero de seguro muchos seguiran pasando por aqui xD.

Yo tenia el mismo problema con ese codigo que nos facilita el curso pero él esta usando Python2 y yo por buscar trabajar con lo mas actualizado me descargue el '3' xD. buscando y buscando aqui esta el codigo que funciona.

```
    import os

    def rename_files():
        # 1) Vamos a obtener el nombre de los archivos
        file_list = os.listdir("D:\prank")
        print(file_list)
        saved_path = os.getcwd()

        print("El directorio activo es " + str(saved_path))
        os.chdir("D:\prank")

        # 2) Hacemos un bucle que los renombrará uno a uno:
        for file_name in file_list :
            os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789')))

    os.chdir(saved_path)
    rename_files()
```

@kikocorreoso tu código esta muy interesante pero por el contrario lo que se busca es quitar los números del *filename* de una serie de imágenes.